# why am i getting undefined when i use ".on" but a value when i use".click"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, socket.io

why do i get "undefined" for "evt.clientX" and "evt.clientY" in the below script when i send it to my node.js server:

```html
<script>
socket.on('message', function(message) {
      
  })
  
  $('#myCanvas').on("pointermove", function(evt) {
   socket.emit('message', ("X: " + evt.clientX + " " + "Y: " + evt.clientY + " on a "+ evt.target.nodeName));
  })
  
</script>
```

Yet when i use the same script but change the ".on" to ".click" it prints out the coordinate for X and Y inside my node.js server correctly. 
Below is the rest of my code that the socket message references to:

```
<script>
      function writeMessage(canvas, message) {
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
    context.font = '10pt Calibri';
    context.fillStyle = 'black';
    context.fillText(message, 10, 25);
  }
  function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
      x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
      y: evt.clientY - rect.top

    };
  }

  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

 canvas.addEventListener('pointermove', function(evt) {
    var x = evt.clientX;
    var y = evt.clientY;
    var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
    var message = 'X: ' + mousePos.x + ' Y: ' + mousePos.y;
    writeMessage(canvas, message);
  }, false);
```

I think it has something to do with my use of jquery? But I could well be completely wrong.
Any help gratefully received! But please. Keep the explanation simple if possible. I'm a bit of a novice at all this!

Many many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I actually worked this one out.. evt.clientX and evt.clientY needed to be changed to evt.pageX and evt.pageY then i had to change the output in the socket message.
Odd as i understand from what i read that pointermove should have worked for clientX and clientY.Anyway it works now so great.